# Hosted Filemaker Database as a desktop icon

Tags: filemaker, shortcut-file

In a follow-up to my previous question which works brilliantly from a compiled application and as a citrix published app, I'm trying to do the same thing from a desktop icon as a shortcut which runs a bat file such as the following command:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\FileMaker\FileMaker Pro 13 Advanced\FileMaker Pro Advanced.exe" fmp:\aci-fms-02\BuildTrac

however when this runs, I am getting the following strange message:

Open Multiple Files
choice 1: Open all files and convert when necessary.
choice 2: Only open current Filemaker Pro files (no conversion)
save converted files in (defaulting to p:/)

I select choice 2 and I'm left with a blank Filemaker menu with no open databases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would probably be easier to create a new internet shortcut in Windows (http://www.7tutorials.com/how-create-shortcuts) and use the URL `fmp://aci-fms-02/BuildTrac` instead of trying to launch it via the client. FileMaker Pro registers to handle the `fmp://` protocol, so anything calling an `fmp://` URL will automatically launch FileMaker Pro for you.

Comment: Thanks again as it worked like a charm creating as a new desktop shortcut rather than trying to modify an existing one which was what I was trying to do.

Comment: You're welcome! There are other benefits to the `fmp://` URL approach, too. For instance, you can call a script in the hosted database to run on launch, pass it parameters, etc. See http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/sharing_data.16.7.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 - correct syntax is:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\FileMaker\FileMaker Pro 13 Advanced\FileMaker Pro Advanced.exe" fmp://aci-fms-02/BuildTrac

or

"C:\Program Files (x86)\FileMaker\FileMaker Pro 13 Advanced\FileMaker Pro Advanced.exe" "fmp://aci-fms-02/BuildTrac.fmp12"

Option 2 - make a local opener file that lives on clients desktop. It's sole purpose is to open the remote file.